I want to make Dynamic Blog Details Page using Next.js 15 App routing and it should be SSR compatible so better for SEO and I am getting below error
I want to make Dynamic Blog Details page for my Next.js website, and below code is working fine during browse under development and in localhost:3000, but when I try to make build then I am getting below error, and I am using Next.js 15.0.3 App routing version and I want to make my page SSR compatible so it can help me for better SEO, can you please help me to fix below error and fulfill my requirements.
Path to my Blog Details Page: /src/app/Blogs/[id]/page.tsx
Build Time Error:
Linting and checking validity of types  .Failed to compile.

.next/types/app/blogs/[id]/page.ts:34:29
Type error: Type 'BlogPageProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'PageProps'.
  Types of property 'params' are incompatible.
    Type '{ id: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<any>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]   

  32 |
  33 | // Check the prop type of the entry function
> 34 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()
     |                             ^
  35 |
  36 | // Check the arguments and return type of the generateMetadata function
  37 | if ('generateMetadata' in entry) {

Page.tsx file
import { Container } from "@mui/material";
import LhContentWithRhSlider from "@/components/LhContentWithRhSlider";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import SEO from "@/components/utils/SEO";
import blogs from "@data/blogs.json";

// Blog type
interface Blog {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string[];
  thumbnail: string;
  sliderImages: string[];
  date: string;
  author: string;
  category: string;
  externalLink: string;
  keywords: string[];
}

const blogsData: Blog[] = blogs;

interface BlogPageProps {
  params: { id: string };
}

// Dynamic Blog Page Component
const BlogDetailsPage = ({ params }: BlogPageProps) => {
  const { id } = params;
  const blog = blogsData.find((b) => b.id === id);

  // If blog is not found, show a 404 page
  if (!blog) {
    notFound();
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      {/* SEO Optimization */}
      <SEO
        title={blog.title}
        description={blog.description.join(" ")}
        url={"www.jogwad.com/blogs/"}
        image={blog.thumbnail}
        keywords={blog.keywords.join(",")}
        canonicalUrl={"www.jogwad.com/blogs/"}
        schemaType={"BlogPost"}
      />

      <LhContentWithRhSlider
        title={blog.title}
        subtitle={`Date: ${new Date(
          blog.date
        ).toLocaleDateString()} | Author: ${blog.author} | Category: ${
          blog.category
        }`}
        description={[blog.description.join(" ")]}
        buttonText={blog.externalLink ? "Visit External Link" : ""}
        buttonLink={blog.externalLink || ""}
        sliderImages={blog.sliderImages}
      />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default BlogDetailsPage;


The error you are getting on line 34, is due to the fact that in nextJs 15, params is asynchronous and you need to make your typescript interface/type to have the params wrapped in promise.
interface BlogPageProps{
params: Promise<{ id: string }>
}

You can read more on nextjs website
Also, you will need to await the id from params and make the BlogDetailsPage async.
const BlogDetailsPage = async ({ params }: BlogPageProps) => {
  const { id } = await params;
}

Hope this helps.
